# Findin matching cells in Excel and get the values then put them into another cell

Tags: excel, count, match, cells

Please help me on this.

i have for example in excel

column A    column B   column C    column D

what i want to do is that when i write something in column C i want excel to check if it exists in any of the cells in column A then do the following.For example lets say i entered number 33 in "C44"  and A"35" has also the same value which is 33 then get the value in B"35" then put it in D"44".Sounds so simple but almost impossible.

u understand? i have searched the whole net no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following formula in D filing down

In essence: it does a look-up in column A for the value in C44 and returns the value in column B with the same row.

=VLOOKUP(C44,A:B,2,FALSE)

If Duplicate values exist in Column A however, the FIRST instance will always be returned.  So to extend your example if A23 has the value of 33, it would get the value from B23 and return it instead.

See image below 1 is duplicate in column A yet in Column C 1 is D each time, not J.

[image]
SOURCE: Press F1 in Excel type VLookup in help.

Comment: Thank u worked And this is even better =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet4!A:B,2,FALSE) this gets the values from different sheets.but i would like to do this using macros because this code can not be extended.any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extended.  I need to understand the context of your problem to provide a different answer.  As it stands, I believe this answer addressed the "stated problem."  If what you're trying to do is different than your stated problem, then state the whole problem! :D